# Image View in Auto Layout using SDWebImage in Storyboards

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview, storyboard, sdwebimage

I'm having no luck getting an image and its **`UIImageView` to show up the correct size in my custom `UITableViewCell`.**  The image is correct, but its place in the `UITableViewCell` is not, and isn't even close.

I don't have enough reputation points to post images sadly.

I have all the suggested constraints Xcode 6 added or suggested, but the **image is showing up huge and in front of everything in my `UITableViewCell`.**

Here's the only code I have related to it.

**ViewController.m**

```
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 600.0;

        NSString *imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", standardResolutionLocal.url];

        __weak UITableViewCell *wcell = api2Cell;
        [wcell.imageView
         sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]
         placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"320x180.gif"]
         ];
```

**CustomTableViewCell.m**

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
       [self.imageViewPic setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
}
```

I'm using iOS 8, Xcode 6, and SDWebImage via CocoaPods.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You can fix the UIImageView size.

Comment: ImageView Content Mode - Aspect Fit

Answer (score 1):

Select your image view and modify the Content Mode as desired - perhaps Aspect Fit will scale it appropriately. If it appears positioned correctly but continues to extend outside the image view bounds, enable Clips to Bounds.